# Name for lemma for BCH formula

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

In my field (of physics) the formula
$$ e^{-X} Y e^X = Y + [Y,X] + \frac{1}{2!} [[Y,X],X] + \ldots $$
for square matrices $X$ and $Y$
is erroneously called the "Baker--Campbell--Hausdorff (BCH) expansion", while it is really a lemma leading up to the "proper" BCH formula. In Brian C. Hall (2015), *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations An Elementary Introduction, Graduate Texts in Mathematics*, it is stated in Proposition 2.25 on page 48.

What is the proper name for the above expansion, if any?

Comment: Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/672329/2451

Comment: Sorry, *Proposition* 2.25 on page 48.

Comment: Some authors use "baker-hausdorff identity" for this formula.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it has a name in mathematics; this is a formal consequence of the fact that the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) of $GL_n$ differentiates to the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, so the adjoint representation of the Lie algebra exponentiates to the adjoint representation of the Lie group; that is, $\exp(\text{ad}_X) = \text{Ad}_{\exp(X)}$.

If I had to give it a name I might call it "exp and ad commute" or "baby BCH."